# example of such continuous and differentiable function

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Could anyone help me to find out the following examples of function on real to reals?

(1) continuous everywhere but not differentiable at $-3,\pi, 29$

Ans: $f(x)=|x+3||x-\pi||x-29|\text{ or } |x+3|+|x-\pi|+|x-29|$ ?

(2) continuous everywhere but differentiable on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$, not differentiable on $\mathbb{Z}$

Ans: $[x]$ ?

(3) Differentiable everywhere and has 2nd derivative except $\pm\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Are you allowed to draw diagrams? It seems to me that having to come up with explicitly defined formulas is too much of a tangential task for someone just learning this. (In my opinion.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $(2)$ you could have

$$ f(x)=\vert\sin(\pi x)\vert$$

For $(3)$ how about

$$ g(x)=(x^2-2)^{4/3} $$

Answer (score 2):

For 1, both answers you cite will work. For 2, is $[x]$ the floor function? That is not a correct example. (Look at the example given by John Wayland Bales for a correct one.) For 3, consider $f(x) = |x-\sqrt 2|^{3/2}|x+\sqrt 2|^{3/2}.$